WordCount failing with Spark 3.5 even though it works with <= 3.3.x
The WordCountDFApp was working fine without setting calling the .master("local[2]") while creating the session (check case None => code block) in versions 3.3.x and lower. However, it is failing with the following error when I migrated the version to 3.5.0. It is working after I have added .master("local[2]") but trying to understand the reason for this.
Error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:414) at

getSparkSession
def getSparkSession(appName: String, clusterCfg: Option[String]): SparkSession = {
    val spark = clusterCfg match {
      case Some(cfg) =>
        // Create spark session for local run. Someone specified "local[x]" as program argument
        SparkSession.builder()
          .appName(appName)
          //Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)!
          // Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver'
          // (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
          .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
          .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
          // Adding these 2 config to work with delta table.
          .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
          .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
          .master(cfg)
          .getOrCreate()
      case None =>
        //Use it during production run
        SparkSession.builder()
          .appName(appName)
          .getOrCreate()
    }
    spark
  }

WordCountDFApp
object WordCountDFApp extends SynapseSparkBase with Logging {
  logInfo("WordCount with Dataframe API")

  val paths = getPaths(args)
  val cluster = getClusterCfg(args)

  if (paths.size > 1) {
    logInfo("More than one file to process")
  }
  logInfo("Path(s): " + paths)
  logInfo("Cluster: " + cluster)

  val spark = getSparkSession("WordCountDFApp", cluster)

  val linesDf: DataFrame = spark.read
    .textFile(paths: _*)
    .toDF("line") //Dataset[Row]
  logInfo("DataFrame before splitting line")
  linesDf.show(false)

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val wordsDf = toWords(linesDf)

  logInfo("Inferred schema")
  wordsDf.printSchema()

  logInfo("DataFrame after splitting the line into words")
  wordsDf.show(false)

  countWords(wordsDf).show(false)

  def toWords(linesDf: DataFrame) = {
    import linesDf.sparkSession.implicits._
    linesDf
      .select($"line",
        explode(split($"line", WhitespaceRegex)).as("word"))
  }

  def countWords(wordsDf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    import wordsDf.sparkSession.implicits._
    wordsDf.filter($"word" =!= "")
      .groupBy(lower($"word"))
      .count()
  }
}


how you're running this?

@Kashyap As a standalone app within IDE
